# theano NotImplementedError

Tags: python, enthought, theano

I am running some theano code making use of tensor.advanced_subtensor
I am getting the following error :

```
NotImplementedError: Could not import inplace_increment, so some advanced indexing features are disabled. They will be available if you update NumPy to version 1.8 or later, or to the latest development version. You may need to clear the cache (theano-cache clear) afterwards.
```

I have the latest version of theano (0.6.0.dev-60b5ccc2bcabb1010714376764daf8a50722cee9) and numpy (1.8.0). Why am I still getting this error? How can I resolve this error? How do I clear theano cache?

Answer (score 0):

The theano cache is usually in `~/.theano/` if you are using *ix.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear Theano cache. Cache live in **~/.theano/** folder.
Follow below steps to clear it manually.

```
 import theano
 print (theano.config.compiledir)
 # and then delete directory returned from above.
```

If you don not want to delete manually then use below command.

```
theano-cache purge
```